# Fixed divs are not rendering properly on IE and navbar on mobile

Tags: html, css

I'm new to front-end technologies. I'm trying to build a CV-website. I have 2 fixed divs. One at the top working as navbar. This div is not properly rendering on mobile devices. It shows only 4 button, rest is not renderin.

My contact-me-form div is showing up at the 800 pixel scroll. I used Jquery for this. Despite my contact-me-form render bad on IE11, i have good view on Chrome browser.

TRUE View:
[IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/fjjgau.png[/IMG]

Corrupted Contact-me-form
[IMG]http://i58.tinypic.com/2ccmoag.png[/IMG]

Corrupted fixed-nav-bar:[IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/5lxil4.jpg[/IMG]

Any suggestion to fix this is welcomed.
btw: I use HTML5.

```
<nav class="navbar">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#aboutme>aboutMe</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#education>education</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#workhistory>workHistory</a></li>
        <li><a class="logo" href="#top">||</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#generalskills>generalSkills</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#knowledge>knowledge</a></li>
        <li><a class="btn btn-alt" href=#myWorks>myWorks</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>


.navbar {
    background-color: #3149e6;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 0;
    opacity: 0.8;
    padding: 0;
    height: 50px;
}

.menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}

.menu li a{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

.btn-alt {
    padding: 10px 30px;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: "Open Sans Condensed";
    color: aliceblue;
}
```

for contact me form:

```
    <div id='contact'>
                <div id='form_container'>
                    <div id='form_elements'>
                        <form action="mailto:@hotmail.comtr?subject=Hey let's have a talk" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend><h3>contactMe</h3></legend>
                                <input type='text' placeholder='Your Name' size="30" name="Name">
                                <input type='text' placeholder='Your E-Mail' size="30" name="E-Mail">
                                <textarea rows="7" cols="40" placeholder='Write your message here.' name="comment"></textarea>
                                <input  type="submit" value="Submit">
                                <input  type="button" value="close" id="close" name="close">
                            </fieldset>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

#contact{
    padding-left: 100px;
    padding-right: 100px;
    width: 320px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
#form_container {
    padding-top: 100px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;

}
#form_elements{
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#form_elements fieldset{
    border: 1px dotted #5690e6;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: black 0px 3px 8px;
}

#form_elements input, textarea{
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 10px auto;
    resize:none;
}
#form_elements input{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your top menu bar doesn't render because you have padding expressed in a fixed-width measure (px) on your btn-alt class.

If you're saying each menu item has to have 30px padding on each side, that means each menu option is going to be 60px + the width of your text. You have 6 of these menu options so that's a MIN width of 360px just for the padding..

A better way to do it is to express the width in a %, then set a min-width property, so the menu items can get pushed into one another..

```
.menu li {
    width: 16.6667%;
    min-width: 100px;
}
```

If you're really interested in optimizing for mobile, you should checkout [@media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

In the meantime here's your code updated http://jsfiddle.net/vs8mwebx/

Comment: Okay you solved my problem but there was a error in your code. When you set relatively width, you missed one div in the middle that called logo div. Because of this there 7 divs not 6. Please update your answer                        .menu li {
    width: 14.428%;
    min-width: 100px;
}